# Group column values into pairs - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
idx  pairs
1   ['000001.jpg', '000002.jpg']
2   ['000006.jpg', '000007.jpg', '000008.jpg', '000004.jpg', '000005.jpg', '000003.jpg']
3   ['000016.jpg', '000020.jpg', '000017.jpg', '000010.jpg', '000011.jpg', '000012.jpg'...]
```

the pairs can have any length of list. I'd like to create a new df of the 'pairs' into a pair where the first part is always the first one in the list of pairs. E.g.:

```
idx pairs
1 ['000001.jpg', '000002.jpg']
2 ['000006.jpg', '000007.jpg']
3 ['000006.jpg', '000008.jpg']
4 ['000006.jpg', '000004.jpg']
5 ['000006.jpg', '000005.jpg']
6 ['000006.jpg', '000003.jpg']
7 ['000016.jpg', '000020.jpg']
8 ['000016.jpg', '000017.jpg']
9 ['000016.jpg', '000010.jpg']
10 ['000016.jpg', '000011.jpg']
11 ['000016.jpg', '000012.jpg']
```

Comment: So, you just want to take the first two values from each `pairs` list?

Comment: Please show some semblance of an attempt at solving or at least researching

Comment: @ignoring_gravity. Each first value paired with each value in the remainder of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a great case for [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

```
df['first'] = df.pairs.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['others'] = df.pairs.apply(lambda x: x[1:])
df = df.explode('others')[['first', 'others']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'pairs': df.values.tolist()})
df = df.rename_axis('idx').reset_index()
df.idx += 1
```

Then the head of `df` will look like this:

```
   idx                     pairs
0    1  [000001.jpg, 000002.jpg]
1    2  [000006.jpg, 000007.jpg]
2    3  [000006.jpg, 000008.jpg]
3    4  [000006.jpg, 000004.jpg]
4    5  [000006.jpg, 000005.jpg]
5    6  [000006.jpg, 000003.jpg]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one using a nested list comprehension and reconstructing the dataframe:

```
from itertools import chain

l = [[[i,j_] for j_ in j] for i, *j in df.pairs]

print(pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(l)))

       0           1
0   000001.jpg  000002.jpg
1   000006.jpg  000007.jpg
2   000006.jpg  000008.jpg
3   000006.jpg  000004.jpg
4   000006.jpg  000005.jpg
5   000006.jpg  000003.jpg
6   000016.jpg  000020.jpg
7   000016.jpg  000017.jpg
8   000016.jpg  000010.jpg
9   000016.jpg  000011.jpg
10  000016.jpg  000012.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'str' method and 'explode':

```
df['first']= df.pairs.str[0]
df['pairs']= df.pairs.str[1:]
                                             pairs       first
0                                       [000002.jpg]  000001.jpg
1  [000007.jpg, 000008.jpg, 000004.jpg, 000005.jp...  000006.jpg
2  [000020.jpg, 000017.jpg, 000010.jpg, 000011.jp...  000016.jpg


df= df.explode("pairs")                                                                                                  

        pairs       first
0  000002.jpg  000001.jpg
1  000007.jpg  000006.jpg
1  000008.jpg  000006.jpg
1  000004.jpg  000006.jpg
1  000005.jpg  000006.jpg
1  000003.jpg  000006.jpg
2  000020.jpg  000016.jpg
2  000017.jpg  000016.jpg
2  000010.jpg  000016.jpg
2  000011.jpg  000016.jpg
2  000012.jpg  000016.jpg
```

Swap the cols:

```
df= df.reindex(columns=["first","pairs"])
```

If you need one list in each row:

```
df= df.reset_index(drop=True).agg(list,axis=1)

0     [000001.jpg, 000002.jpg]
1     [000006.jpg, 000007.jpg]
2     [000006.jpg, 000008.jpg]
3     [000006.jpg, 000004.jpg]
4     [000006.jpg, 000005.jpg]
5     [000006.jpg, 000003.jpg]
6     [000016.jpg, 000020.jpg]
7     [000016.jpg, 000017.jpg]
8     [000016.jpg, 000010.jpg]
9     [000016.jpg, 000011.jpg]
10    [000016.jpg, 000012.jpg]
dtype: object
```

**Edit:**
'reindex' is not necessary in this case:

```
df['tail']= df.pairs.str[1:]
df['pairs']= df.pairs.str[0]
df= df.explode("tail")
etc.
```

]